# odoo mobile framework call method on odoo 10

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-mobile

can anyone help me out with my issue?
 i define a method called **get_order_no** on odoo 10

```
@api.one
@api.returns('self')
def get_order_no(self):
    order_no = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('car.seat')
    return order_no
```

then i call it on mobile side,here is code block

```
ServerDataHelper helper = getServerDataHelper();
OArguments oArguments = new OArguments();
oArguments.add(new JSONArray().put(2));
Object billno = helper.callMethod("get_order_no", oArguments);
```

finaly i  got an exception from odoo 10.

> TypeError:Mixing apples and oranger:car.seat().concat(170108027)

**170108027** is generated by *next_by_code* method.

Another  strange thing is: only first time call the **get_order_no** method success.
when i debug the app again,can't call success,even not go into breakpoint in **get_order_no** method.
only when i reinstall the app.the method can be called with the error above.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was resolved .i made big mistake. when call server method .the android code should be write in AsyncTask method .